# Setting XAML Style on an undeclared subelement

Tags: c#, xaml, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion RibbonMenu and currently I have the XAML

```
<syncfusion:RibbonMenuItem Header="New attempt">
    <syncfusion:RibbonMenuItem.ContextMenu >
        <ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource HiddenContextMenu}"/>
    </syncfusion:RibbonMenuItem.ContextMenu>
</syncfusion:RibbonMenuItem>
```

with the style rule

```
<Style x:Key="HiddenContextMenu" TargetType="ContextMenu">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
</Style>
```

This works fine and will hide the context menu successfully. However, I would like to only have this XAML while still achieving the same in regards to the context menu:

```
<syncfusion:RibbonMenuItem Header="New attempt"/>
```

Is that possible or would I have to stick with the original solution?